# Set BOTH, android:onClick AND OnTouchListener

Tags: android, button

How it is possible to set an android:onClick method AND an OnTouchListener on the same button? I really need this for my app.

I know about the differences of them and taking only android:onClick or OnTouchListener does work. As soon as I try to do both, just the OnTouchListener works.

I need this for different functionalities in different layouts.

Just for better understanding. With android:onClick I meant the method you assign this button to **in the xml file** like  android:onClick="InitMethod"

Comment: not possible. you'll have to do with just one.

Comment: really? I totally should table-flip my coffee over my android phones -.-    thanks anyway..

Comment: actually, I may have misread your question. I read you were looking for using onClickListener.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can use both onClick and onTouch on a same button, but OnTouch callback you'll get motionEvent like ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP , ACTION_DOWN etc, Don't forget to return false ([Details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html))in onTouch callback. Please refer the below code

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("test", "ontouch");
                return false;
            }
        });
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("test", "onclick");
            }

        });
```

Just do the operations you want to do in the call backs onTouch and onClick respectively.
Please NOte click is a action performed when user press the button and release but Touch will be taken when user presses it.

So on a single click the log will be like this. 1.ACTION_DOWN, 2.ACTION_UP 3. onClick

```
03-22 16:19:39.735: D/test(682): ontouch
03-22 16:19:39.735: D/test(682): ontouch
03-22 16:19:39.735: D/test(682): onclick
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but that wasn't I was looking for. You got my idea about the ontouchlistener right. But with android:onClick I meant the method, you assign this button to IN THE XML FILE. Sorry if that wasn clearly said in my question

Comment: @user2161301 There is no any difference if you assign the method from the xml or from code. The key moment here is just to **return false** in `OnTouchListener()` - if `false` is returned, then system will go on with proceeding tap event and finally `onClick()` method will be called.

Comment: @user216130 There is no difference in assigning onclick or ontouch methods in your xml. You can have your own method of ontouch or onclick as afterclick ,InitMethod or anything u want. but make sure your custom method have the same signature of the above onclick and ontouch.methods.

Comment: I now got it in another way, but i'm still wondering, why it didn't word for me..

Comment: I've found this is simpler than combining them, which is covered heavily on other posts. For my game I often use ontouch to change button color for down touches and onclick for button actions.